# Firing ctrl+r, ctrl+a, ctrl+q events on a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-events

I need to fire the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> events when a user clicks on a button.

I was working on the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Button1').click(function () {
        var evt = $.Event("keypress");
        evt.keyCode = 81;
        evt.ctrlKey = true;
        evt.shiftKey = true;
        $(document).trigger(evt);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't simulate browser control keys, but you can simulate their effects.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> refreshes.

```
function refresh() {
    location.reload(true);
}
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> selects everything. Code is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369789/jquery-method-to-select-the-contents-of-a-whole-page).

```
function selectAll() {
    var e = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var r = document.createRange(); r.selectNodeContents(e);
    var s = window.getSelection();
    s.removeAllRanges();
    s.addRange(r);
}
```

I am not sure what <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> is supposed to do; if it quits the browser, that one isn't possible.