# Map ctrl + tab to one key with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add a certain shortcut to a macro extension i'm using. I'm trying to make it so that by pressing the <kbd>Q</kbd> key, it sends <kbd>Ctrl + Tab</kbd> so I could switch tabs a lot quicker. I know that the keycode for Ctrl is 17 and tab is 9, but I don't know how I could map them both to the <kbd>q</kbd> key. Any help or explanation on how to do this would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: you can't do that

Comment: Similar Quetion was asked on this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25763872/firing-ctrlr-ctrla-ctrlq-events-on-a-button-click